# Can I get a Saudi Arabian transit visa if driving from UAE to Jordan by car?

Tags: transit-visas, overland, saudi-arabia, emirates, jordan

Is it possible to get Saudi Arabia transit visa in Dubai for overland crossing to Jordan? I plan to travel Africa by 4WD. The idea is to visit Iran first, take a ferry from Bandar Abbas to Emirates and then to cross Saudi Arabia to Jordan for further travel to Egypt. Some sources suggest that a transit KSA visa is possible, but I can't find any latest information. I am Australian and not a resident of any GCC state, the car is not registered there either.

Comment: I've only heard of GCC nationals and GCC permanent residents managing it. [See here on flyertalk for one such trip report](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/trip-reports/1556689-road-trip-saudi-arabia-qatar.html). Maybe look at some of the references from that thread?

Comment: Hi Gagravarr! I read this trip report already before posting here. As you mentioned this guy was a resident of Emirates, but I am not, so the report information is not relevant, but thanks for your message anyway! I spent lots of time searching the web, but could find nothing recent on this topict. Hope that someone on StackExchange can shed  a ray of hope for me! :)

Comment: Besides the transit visas, it seems that the Kingdom is about to reintroduce tourist visas: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72934

Answer (score 8):

A transit visa is indeed possible (they are issued all the time to commercial vehicle drivers and third country nationals), but recently they have stopped issuing them for non-nationals - and issue them on a case-by-case basis.

*By national I mean citizen of the destination country; for example an Egyptian national traveling by road from UAE to Egypt.*

You'll need to have already obtained:

1. Triptych/CDP for your vehicle.
2. Visa for Jordan in advance if required. If you are eligible for non-visa entry, you may get a pass - but if you are eligible for *visa on arrival* you will still have to obtain a visa in advance.
3. Permanent residency in the UAE OR visa free entry into the UAE; you must be deportable to the UAE.

I must warn you - due to the current political climate, if they see you have visited Iran you may get denied transit through Saudi.

Comment: (+1) By "nationals", you mean nationals from another GCC country (or whatever it's called these days)? Surely, Saudi citizens don't need a visa to enter their own country, or do they?

Comment: Yes I mean nationals of the destination country. For example, an Egyptian national traveling from UAE to Egypt by road. GCC nationals enjoy visa free access across the GCC member states; and Saudi nationals do not need visas to enter Saudi (they don't even need passports, just their Saudi ID card is sufficient).

Comment: Oh OK, might be worth editing your answer, it wasn't clear at all to me.

Comment: Thanks to your reply Burhan! I'm Australian, hence "non-national". I also planned to go arrive to UAE from Iran. All things considered my chances getting a KSA transit visa are probably close to zero.