# How to travel to Lebanon without flying?

Tags: sea-travel, overland, lebanon

I would like to travel to Lebanon this October and prefer not to fly, mainly for ecological reasons. Which options do I have?

Starting point would be nearly anywhere in Europe. Driving myself is not an option for me.

Top priority for me is that the route is safe, somewhat cheap and ecologically favorable. I don't mind it being laborious and slow.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65683/discussion-on-question-by-paul-paulsen-how-to-travel-to-lebanon-without-flying).

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2114/what-would-be-an-example-of-a-currently-possible-overland-route-from-europe-to-i

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that crossing into Israel is simply impossible but that the border with Syria is technically open so it might be possible to find a shared taxi from Damascus or something. Of course, you need to get there in the first place and the whole of Syria and even large parts of Lebanon (the entire Bekaa valley and all land borders) are not particularly safe and completely off-limit as far as any official travel advisory is concerned.

Options to come by sea are limited as well. I am aware of some freighters taking passengers and stopping in Lebanon but that's not cheap and they explicitly disallow disembarking there. The only halfway realistic option therefore seems to be a ferry from [Taşucu to Tripoli](http://www.akgunlerdenizcilik.com/) but it seems that it's not operating at the moment. Tripoli itself is not as bad as the border but still not particularly recommended. I haven't been there personally.

Comment: There used to be a ferry from Taşucu to Tripoli, but it is currently not operating. You can't book any tickets for it and the time table is 'empty': https://www.akgunlerbilet.com/sefer_takvimi.php

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo That may very well be but I don't speak Turkish and I am not sure what I am looking at. I see a table with a bunch of dates.

Comment: The time table URL does not seem to contain the route. Go to https://www.akgunlerbilet.com/online_bilet.php?dil=en (online ticket order form in English), select the Taşucu-Tripoli route and then click on 'Click here to view timetable'.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo OK, I see it, thanks, somehow following the link directly showed me another route or something.